# Formlula that changes days in month based on current year, but only shows workdays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I found this nice template from [Vertex42](https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/class-attendance-template.html) to track attendance in classes.

I am trying to modify the template so that it only shows workdays (as there is no class on weekends).  The formula used is above my Excel skill level, so I hope someone else can figure it out.

The function looks like this, where C7 is the first day of the month:

```
=@IF(C7="";"";INDEX({"Su";"M";"Tu";"W";"Th";"F";"Sa"};WEEKDAY(C7;1)))
```

The function for C7, where AB3 is the year, and AB2 is the month:

```
=DATE(AB3;@INDEX({1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9\10\11\12};MATCH(AB2;monthNames;0));1)
```

Screenshot of the template:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate *Sat* and *Sun* from row 7 and you can use the existing formula in row 6. In fact you can even shorten the formula in row 6 since the *Sa* and *Sun* options are no longer necessary.

C7 should be,

```
=IF(TEXT(WORKDAY(DATEVALUE("1-"&LEFT($AB2; 3)&"-"&$AB3)-1; COLUMN(A:A)); "mmmm")=$AB2; WORKDAY(DATEVALUE("1-"&LEFT($AB2; 3)&"-"&$AB3)-1; COLUMN(A:A)); "")
```

[image]

This has the advantage of treating the dates in row 7 as actual dates.

You can add a list of holidays to the WORKDAY or WORKDAY.INTL function. WORKDAY.INTL allows weekends that are not standard(e.g. not *Sat* & *Sun*).

Comment: Thank you, that works for the first part.
However, it does not fix the dates. Now I have M M M, (Monday, Monday, Monday), for the first three dates in june. I tried to add the WORKDAY function at the end, and put C7 as the startdate, but I cant get i to work

Comment: Figured it out. Created a DATE with the first day of the month, then a WORKDAY, that references the DATE. The next field then references the first WORKDAY.

Comment: I believe we came to the same conclusion. (see the [edit] above made just 3 minutes before your last comment)

Comment: Looks like we did - thank you for the help

Comment: Here's a slightly shorter formula for row 6. `=TRIM(MID("   M TuW ThF", WEEKDAY(C7)*2,  2))`